# Python dictionary search not finding result given a string

Tags: python, regex, dictionary, search, key

I'm writing code for a project and it searches a text file for occurrences of a word on each line. When I use a example text file and search for a word it always prints out "No results for: " even if the word I searched for is in it. Did I setup the dictionary wrong or something?

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Nov 14 11:31:17 2017

@author: Ben Roux
"""

import re
from collections import Counter

stringinput = raw_input("Please enter a filename to open: ")
dictionary = {}

def openFile(stringinput):
    try:
        filevariable = open(stringinput, 'r')
        return filevariable
    except IOError:
        print("Cannot Find File!")

def readData(stringinput):
    filevariable = open(stringinput, 'r')
    rawline = filevariable.readline()
    line = 1
    while (rawline !=""):
        pl1 = rawline.replace(",","")
        pl2 = pl1.replace("'","")
        pl3 = pl2.replace("!","")
        pl4 = pl3.replace("-"," ")
        pl5 = pl4.replace(".","")
        pl6 = re.sub('(\\b[A-Za-z] \\b|\\b [A-Za-z]\\b)', '', pl5)
        pl7 = pl6.lower()
        checkdictionary = sorted(Counter(pl7.split()).items())
        for i in range(len(checkdictionary)):
            if checkdictionary[i] in dictionary:
                 firstvalue = dictionary.get(checkdictionary[i])
                 newvalue = str(firstvalue) + ", " + str(line)
                 d1 = {checkdictionary[i]: newvalue}
                 dictionary.update(d1)
            else:
                d2 = {checkdictionary[i]: line}
                dictionary.update(d2)
        rawline = filevariable.readline()
        line+=1

def processText(dictionary, searchkey):
    if searchkey in dictionary:
        print(str(searchkey) + " Appears On Lines: " + (str(dictionary[searchkey])))
    else:
        print("No results for: " + str(searchkey))

while (True):
    try:
        openFile(stringinput)
        readData(stringinput)
        searchkey = raw_input("Enter a keyword to search for: ")
        processText(dictionary, searchkey)
        break
    except IOError:
        break
```

Comment: Before you run your `processText(dictionary, searchkey)` you should print out the contents of dictionary to make sure it's fully populated

Comment: This is what I get:  {('dog', 1): 3, ('yellow', 1): 2, ('fox', 1): 1, ('kite', 1): '2, 4', ('green', 1): 4, ('brown', 1): '1, 3'}     and when I search for 'fox' I get no results found

Comment: Well then dictionary is not created correctly. Your keys are tuples. It should be something like `{'dog': 1, 'yellow': 1, ...}` or else `{'dog': 3, 'yellow': 2, ...}` - if you search for `('fox', 1)` it will return the value `'1'`

Comment: Can you print out your `pl7` variable at the time you instantiate it? What way is your data?

Comment: Can you provide some input for the script? What's the contents of your file that you parse?

Comment: pl7 is   "brown fox yellow kite brown dog green kite"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update this following code;

```
if checkdictionary[i][0] in dictionary:
    firstvalue = dictionary.get(checkdictionary[i][0])
    newvalue = str(firstvalue) + ", " + str(line)
    d1 = {checkdictionary[i][0]: newvalue}
    dictionary.update(d1)        
else:
    d2 = {checkdictionary[i][0]: line}
    dictionary.update(d2)
```

Comment: Now my pl7 printout is {0: '1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4'} I'm still getting no result when I search fox.

Comment: this works, and the first answer was really close and I made that work too. I'll approve this one.

Answer (score 1):

@AK47's answer for changing the if else statement works and this also works:

```
checkdictionary = sorted(Counter(pl7.split()).items())
```

change to

```
checkdictionary = pl7.split()
```